# Propagate traceparent header when using recordMetadataChannel

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I use spring boot 3.
After sending message to kafka, using spring cloud stream, I would like to log offset and partition of sent message with the traceId from the thread which sent the message.

Here's code:
`build.gradle` contains next dependencies:

```
  implementation "io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus"
  implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing'
  implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
```

application.yml producer contains `recordMetadataChannel: meta` and `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.enable-observation: true`

And configuration class contains:

```
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel meta() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }



    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow logMeta() {
        return f -> f.channel("meta")
                .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                    log.info("Log metadata from headers")
                    return payload;
                });
    }
```

While I'm able to fetch the metadata, I would like to log it with traceId and spanId in MDC. The Kafka headers obtained in IntegrationFlow don't contain `traceparent` header, though I can see them in the message, which is sent further.
Is there any way to receive the traceId for logging?

Comment: MDC won't work because the metadata message is published on a different thread; however, the message sent to the metadafa channel contains all the headers from the sent message, plus the metadata.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
So, is there no way to access the `traceparent` header? I see no `traceparent` header in the headers (though I can see it in the kafka topic, where the message was sent), and all I can operate in IntegrationFlow are MessageHeaders and Payload.

Comment: The instrumentation is done by brave at a much lower level in the `kafka-clients`; Spring doesn't have access to it. One thing you could do is add a `ProducerInterceptor` to the producer configs and do your logging there. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_interceptor.classes You would need to capture the header in `onSend()` and log in `onAcknowledgement` (this assumes Brave instruments the header before the `onSend()` call. But I don't know how easy it would be to correlate the two calls because they are on different threads.